# How do I validate e-mail with filter_val in a php session?

Tags: php, email-validation

The following is my most recently failed attempt:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST") {

 if (!empty($_SESSION['email'])) {

      if(!filter_var($_SESSION['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
          echo "Required: valid e-mail address";
          } else {
                  echo "Your email is " . $_SESSION['email'] . "<br />";
                 } 

   } else {
     echo "Required: valid e-mail address";
          }
}
```

// When the variable is empty, I get the correct message, but if I enter an invalid or valid e-mail, nothing echoes. I have been at this all day.

Comment: I feel like we need a bit more information. If nothing is echoing out at all, then some error must be firing. Anything in your error log, or if you turn on error_reporting?

Comment: Why exactly are you checking a session for a valid e-mail? Why are you not checking before setting the email session variable?

Comment: Please consider using [Dominic Sayers' excellent `is_email` library](http://code.google.com/p/isemail/) instead of PHP's filter.  [The built-in filter fails a number of RFC-compliant addresses](http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail/results.php).

Comment: error_reporting displays a 2039 integer value.

Comment: Good point, Prisoner, I will change my approach to check these values earlier, though I am not confident that doing so will resolve my current problem ... maybe.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(filter_var($_SESSION['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // it's valid so do something
}
else {
    // it's not valid so do something else
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this is different than the OP's original code.

Comment: this one worked for me on my computer. so i posted the solution. thats it.

Comment: Same error; same result. If the same code is working for Coding-Freak, then my error must be somewhere else. I will look for other possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Is old post but this will help.

```
function valid_email($email) 
{
    if(is_array($email) || is_numeric($email) || is_bool($email) || is_float($email) || is_file($email) || is_dir($email) || is_int($email))
        return false;
    else
    {
        $email=trim(strtolower($email));
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) return $email;
        else
        {
            $pattern = '/^(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){255,})(?!(?:(?:\\x22?\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7E]\\x22?)|(?:\\x22?[^\\x5C\\x22]\\x22?)){65,}@)(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22))(?:\\.(?:(?:[\\x21\\x23-\\x27\\x2A\\x2B\\x2D\\x2F-\\x39\\x3D\\x3F\\x5E-\\x7E]+)|(?:\\x22(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0B\\x0C\\x0E-\\x1F\\x21\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7F]|(?:\\x5C[\\x00-\\x7F]))*\\x22)))*@(?:(?:(?!.*[^.]{64,})(?:(?:(?:xn--)?[a-z0-9]+(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*\\.){1,126}){1,}(?:(?:[a-z][a-z0-9]*)|(?:(?:xn--)[a-z0-9]+))(?:-+[a-z0-9]+)*)|(?:\\[(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9][:\\]]){7,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,5})?)))|(?:(?:IPv6:(?:(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){5}:)|(?:(?!(?:.*[a-f0-9]:){5,})(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3})?::(?:[a-f0-9]{1,4}(?::[a-f0-9]{1,4}){0,3}:)?)))?(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))(?:\\.(?:(?:25[0-5])|(?:2[0-4][0-9])|(?:1[0-9]{2})|(?:[1-9]?[0-9]))){3}))\\]))$/iD';
            return (preg_match($pattern, $email) === 1) ? $email : false;
        }
    }
}
```

This function use filter_var and check if email have "super domains".